# How do I make Linux boot faster on a Mac?

Tags: linux, boot, macintosh

I have installed GNU/Linux on a Macintosh computer as the sole operating system. However, it takes around one and a half minute to start the computer. During the first 40 seconds the screen is gray. Then the screen is black and the monitor says "no signal." Finally, the Linux splash screen is shown and from that point the boot is quick.

- Computer: Mac Mini mid 2007 with Intel Core 2 Duo CPU and 1 GB memory
- Operating System: Lubuntu 16.04 i386

I feel that this question really needs a canonical answer that can be easy to find for people who have the same problem as I have.

Update 2018-03-25:

I have tried to follow the instructions at http://mac.linux.be/content/single-boot-linux-without-delay. However, when I boot from the rEFIt medium I get the error message

> gptsync: GPT partition of type 'Unknown' found, will not touch this
>   disk

Comment: I have no Macintosh computer but that first part of the boot time is incompressible, I'm afraid. This all occurs during the phase that is disguised as the "Power-On Self Test", during which the hardware is advertised to "initialize itself" and perform "*other various checks*". From your question Linux in itself seems to already boot fast enough, right?

Comment: @Nasha Quite a few years ago I experienced the same problem with a different Mac Mini (late 2009 model) which I managed to solve. On this computer the initial screen is now gray only for a few seconds. Unfortunately, I don't remember how I solved it.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Bootcamp? GRUB/LILO timeout?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Please, elaborate.

Comment: One of the factors might be a GRUB timeout. There could be others, including having configured a silent boot, I think SuSE does that by default.

Comment: What interface are you using for video output btw? HDMI output only is turned on quite late during the boot phase.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The monitor uses the DVI input.

Comment: Do you know the Intel model? have tried using `nomodeset=0 ` ?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have added CPU info to the question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Correct me if I'm wrong, but do you really think a kernel parameter can affect the "gray screen delay". As far as I understand when I see the gray screen Linux has not begin booting yet.